# firebase t.INTERNAL.registerService is not a function (with vue) on deployment

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

When i deploy my vue application with firebase deploy i get a error in de console. I only use the firebase firestore and deployment.

t.INTERNAL.registerService is not a function

has someone a solution?

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.22",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.6",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "firebase": "^6.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-firestore": "^0.3.22",
    "vue-izitoast": "^1.2.1",
    "vue-moment": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.6.2",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1",
    "vuexfire": "^3.0.0-alpha.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/custom-forms": "^0.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That particular error is usually a problem in the import of the firebase/app library dependency.

Try running the following command and it should fix the issue:

```
npm install @firebase/app --save
```